# UnauthorizedAccessException

Tags: c#, ftpwebrequest

I am working with the tutorial here: http://www.devtoolshed.com/content/c-download-file-progress-bar and I am receiving an UnauthorizedAccessException on the following line of code

```
using (Stream streamLocal = new FileStream(sPathToWriteFilesTo, 
FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None)) 
{ 
    //... 
}
```

Perhaps it is something with permissions of the file I am trying to read? It is just a simple text file requested using FTP (instead of HTTP as the tutorial shows).

```
string sFtpToReadFilesFrom = "ftp://<user>:<pass>@mysite.tk/updates/App_Data/output_log.txt";
string sPathToWriteFilesTo = Application.StartupPath + "\\App_Data";

Uri url = new Uri(sFtpToReadFilesFrom);
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(url);
request.Timeout = 10000;
request.ReadWriteTimeout = 10000;
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.GetFileSize;
FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
response.Close();
```

If anyone sees any immediate red flags with the FtpWebRequest please do let me know. I am primarily concerned with the UnauthorizedAccessException and how to fix that.

Comment: do you have access to the FTP folder? If you supply credentials to the ftp are they correct.

Comment: Yes. I can add request.Credentials = new NetworkCredentails("u","p"); and I will still get the UnAuthEx.

Comment: Verify that the user account has read permissions for that path and file.

Comment: Make sure the final path you use is actually path to a file... From code sample it feels like you may be trying to create file with the same name as folder.

Comment: Your local file has nothing to do with FTP at all. You can just delete everything FTP related from this question. It is a red herring that already has confused you and others.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Win10 this line may cause errors:

```
string sPathToWriteFilesTo = Application.StartupPath + "\\App_Data";
```

Since one of updates you can't copy files from network location directly into some folders. Try downloads folder or some directly at C drive (e.g. `c:\TMP`).